# Showing that the property of "being null" is arithmetical.

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $c \in {^\omega\omega}$ be a real. We say that $c$ is a $G_\delta$ code iff  $c(0) \gt 1$. And we let $A_c = \bigcap_n(\bigcup\{O_{s_i}: c(2^n3^{i+1}) = 1\})$, where the $s_i$'s are a fixed recursive enumeration of $^{\lt\omega}\omega$ and $O_{s_i} = \{ x \in {^\omega\omega} : s_i \subset x \}$. Now there is this statement in the proof of theorem $14.1$ of Kanamori's "The Higher Infinite" which I can't figure out:

---

> If $C \subseteq {^2(^\omega\omega)}$ is given by 
>   $$C(x, c) \leftrightarrow c \text{ is a } G_\delta \text{ code for a null set } \wedge x \in A_c $$
>   then it is straightforward to check that $C$ is arithmetical.

---

My thoughts: 
 The "$x \in A_c$" part is arithmetical since we can check it using $\forall^0 n \exists^0 i(c(2^n3^{i+1}) = 1 \wedge x \in O_{s_i})$, which is clearly arithmetical. The "$c \text{ is a } G_\delta \text{ code}$" part is obvious. But I am struggling to put "$A_c \text{ is null}$" into arithmetical terms. One idea that popped into my mind was using the fact that if $B = \bigcap_n O_n$ is $G_\delta$ then $m_L(B) = \inf\{m_L(\bigcap^K_{n=0}O_n) : K \in \omega\}$. But if I were to use this then it would be complicated to translate the codes to the $O_n$'s and even then I would have to somehow define $\frac{1}{n}$ in arithmetic so I could use a formula like: $\forall^0 N \exists^0 i(m_L(\bigcap^i_{n=0}O_n) \lt \frac{1}{N+1})$ and I would also need to see if $m_L(X)$ is arithmetical and that would ultimately amount to translating measure theory and real analysis into second order arithmetic. I know that this must be easier than I think it is and I would be really glad if someone could help me out.

Comment: In the definition of $A_c$, if the $\bigcap_n$ were $\bigcap_{n=0}^k$ for a finite $k$, then you could express the result as a finite union of disjoint intervals, whose measure would be easy. Now you could let $k\to\infty$ and check whether the measure goes to zero?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I don't know what an interval means in the case of the Baire space, if you mean the $O_{s_i}$'s, then I don't see why evaluting the intersection would necessarily give a finite union, it may very well be infinite. Also just checking whether the measure is getting closer to $0$ would require translating some machinery from real analysis, wouldn't it?

Comment: I was assuming that you make a measure on ${}^\omega\omega$ but choosing an appropriate bijection with $\mathbb R$ and transferring the Lebesgue measure. With a "reasonable" bijection, $O_{s_i}$ ends up being an interval. If that is not what is going on, my proposal might be nonsense.

Comment: You're right that "finite union" was a mistake -- but you do get a _countable_ union of finite intersection of $O_s$s. Each of these finite intersections is either empty or a particular $O_s$ itself, and you can define that you don't look at those of them that are contained in a different part of the countable union.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Yeah, it can certainly be written down as a countable union of disjoint "intervals"(here meaning as the $O_s$'s). But then again when computing the measure we are facing the evaluation of a series which then we need to go towards real analysis, and frankly I think there should be a shortcut to this problem and it shouldn't be complicated like this.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Rational numbers and actually a big part of analysis can be dealt with in arithmetic perfectly well. A rational number $\frac{n}{m}$ can be coded as the pair $(n,m)$, which in turn can be coded as a single natural number. Also the usual operations and the order on the rationals can be defined arithmetically on this coding.

Comment: @Jonathan, That's fair but I don't think Kanamori had that in mind because he does't mention it and gives no references. Can you please give me some preferably short reference on it? Also another problem that arises is that the series might converge to an irrational number, I suspect that such "definable" irrational numbers should be easy to code as well, but all this makes me hesitant to go through developing all the theory by myself.